# Creation of a SharePoint User Adoption Guide

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

I have been given the task of creating a basic introduction to SharePoint 2013 User Adoption Guide. It is to be aimed at enterprise and not IT Pros. I have had no previous experience of SharePoint and was given this task so I would be learning the basic info associated with the software as I am writing the document.

My main concern is content. I am unsure how to structure the guide without writing it as if the reader is 5 years old! Although I think that might be the best thing to consider whilst creating it? The document is to focus on a simple introduction to SharePoint 2013, but leaving out the stuff the IT Pros need to know and including the basic info needed to walk clients through the introductory process of SharePoint 2013 and its features for example, "How to make a site" etc.

Any information / advice would be much appreciated.